# startActivity not working inside onMessageReceived in fcm

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I know there are many thread discussing this problem. I have tried almost all of solutions on that threads, but unfortunately that didn't work in my case.

Basically, what I want to do is, I want to start an activity immediately after `onMessageReceived` is called without issuing notification.

This is my code:

```
override fun onMessageReceived(p0: RemoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(p0)
    "new notif".ea()
    val data = p0.data
    val title = data["title"]
    val body = data["body"]
    val type = data["type"]

    if (type == NEW_ORDER) {
        val order = data["data"]!!.fromJsonObject(OrderModel::class.java)
        NewOrderActivity.open(this, order)
    }
...
```

```
class NewOrderActivity : BaseActivity() {

    companion object {
        fun open(c: Context, order: OrderModel) = c.startActivity(Intent(c, NewOrderActivity::class.java).apply {
            addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            putExtra("order", order.toJsonObject())
        })
    }
...
```

The problem is, if the app is in foreground, `NewOrderActivity` is opened. But if the app is in background, `NewOrderActivity` is not opened. I have tried using `BroadcastReceiver` but that also does not work. Current `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` is set to `29`. I have changed it to `28` but also does not work

Comment: Are you getting ant error ?

Comment: There is no ant error

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts

Comment: i think it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/37845174/12676247

Comment: @JyotishBiswas The payload is set properly (using Data Messages). The onMessageReceived is always getting called.

Comment: @ib-ganz you can try click_action like the 1st answer

Comment: any solution for this?

Comment: Did you find solution for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission is not granted by the user. In case someone needs to know how to grant the `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` persmission, here is the link
[SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW - How to get this permission automatically on Android 6.0 and targetSdkVersion 23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36016369/system-alert-window-how-to-get-this-permission-automatically-on-android-6-0-an)

Comment: This works for me! Thank you. Android has poor error message feedback, Instead of giving you an error, in this case it just fail silently.

Answer (score 1):

> There are two types of messages data messages and notification
> messages. Data messages are handled here in onMessageReceived whether
> the app is in the foreground or background. Data messages are the type
> traditionally used with GCM. Notification messages are only received
> here in onMessageReceived when the app is in the foreground. When the
> app is in the background an automatically generated notification is
> displayed. When the user taps on the notification they are returned to
> the app. Messages containing both notification and data payloads are
> treated as notification messages. The Firebase console always sends
> notification messages.

**Example code** :- You need to specify click_action in your notification payload like this

```
$noti = array
    (
    'icon' => 'new',
    'title' => 'title',
    'body' => 'new msg',
    'click_action' => 'open_NewOrderActivity'
);
```

Now in `manifest` file do this in your `NewOrderActivity` activity tag

```
<activity
           android:name=".NewOrderActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="open_NewOrderActivity" /> // should be same as in click action
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
           </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: "fields": {
    "registration_ids": [
      "xxx"
    ],
    "notification": {
      "data": "",
      "type": "new-order",
      "body": "xxx",
      "click_action": "OPEN_NEW_ORDER_ACTIVITY",
      "title": "xxx"
    }
  }

Comment: and in manifest

<activity
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:showOnLockScreen="true"
            android:name=".activity.NewOrderActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="OPEN_NEW_ORDER_ACTIVITY" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: can you remove these paramters from activity tag  android:launchMode="singleInstance" android:showOnLockScreen="true"

Comment: remove these params and check